# I custom board with STM32F429IGT6 ST-Link v3 using the ST-Link Utility. "No target detected"

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, schematics

I did my own board with STM32F429IGT6, and connect the ST-Link v3 using the ST-Link Utility. "No target detected".
Previously I had made my own boards, and the minimum connection is Vcaps to 2.2uF capacitors, nRst with 10k pull-up, and Boot to ground.The boards worked fine. 
The device is not detected by the programmer. Already checked supply voltages and grounds. Also SWDIO and SWCLK wires.

```
PIN 124  (TMS_SWDIO) -> PA13
PIN 137  (TCK_SWCLK) -> PA14
```

[image]

Comment: Do you connect all 4 pins of the SWD to ST-Link?

Comment: Yes, everything connected properly. Guess I gotta stop buying stm32f4 from China...

Answer (score 12):

The BYPASS pin should be low to to enable internal regulator. Now it is high and disables internal regulator.

Comment: You are right, that is the error. Thank you